# Including a PHP Class from a subdomain

Tags: php, directory

Basically, I have a class `Avian` that contains logic for some basic things such as:

1. Connecting to MySQL
2. Checking login status
3. Displaying the navigation bar

These files are stored in "projectavian" which is a folder within my host's root directory and is the folder for all files that will display on mydomain.com.

I've gone and set up a few subdomains such as dev.mydomain.com. My host creates folders for subdomains in the root directory alongside the "projectavian" folder. The furthest back that I seem to be able to go from within a HTML/PHP page in "projectavian" or the folder for my subdomain is up to this folder only (ie I can't actually access the root by going `"/subdomain_folder"` or adding as many `"../"s` as I want.

All I need to do is use include or require to get my PHP class from mydomain.com on a page that's at dev.mydomain.com. Obviously you can't do `include "http://somedomain.com/file.php"`. Is there maybe a PHP function that can access the server root directory?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it sounds like that `Avian` class should be split up into some smaller classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use magic constants combined with dirname like this:

```
$root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
```

which lets you access your root directory and from there you can do something like:

```
$path = $root . '/subdomain_folder/' . $filename;
```

check out these references for both dirname and the magic constant

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 1):

The fact you can't jump back and get into your subdomain folders is a restriction placed by your host - you might be able to speak to them about it.

You can actually do `include "http://somedomain.com/file.php"`, but `file.php` needs to output valid PHP rather than the result of processing that PHP. This means that the file is then publicly accessible and anyone can view your code, which may be a security issue. Maybe wrap it in [PHP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)?

Comment: Damn, I figured this was the reason; was hoping there was a way to force access to other folders on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? It could likely be either incorrect permissions, or a PHP [open_basedir](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20open_basedir) restriction (most likely). You can turn off open_basedir and/or PHP safe mode via php.ini.